# Php CURL Though I set the header as application/json the request goes as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to POST JSON in my code.
Though I set the header `Content_Type:application/json` 
the receiving server gets as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

```
$Content_Type = "application/json";
$header_info = "X_RESTBUS_MESSAGE_ID:".$X_RESTBUS_MESSAGE_ID.","."X_BU_ID:".$X_BU_ID.","."Content_Type:".$Content_Type;
$url = $server_url;
    $content = json_encode($body_data);

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array($header_info));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

but the server receiving the POST call gets as

```
13 > X_RESTBUS_MESSAGE_ID: <aaaaa>,X_BU_ID:<xxxx>,Content_Type:application/json
13 > Accept: */*
13 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
13 > Content-Length: 641
13 > Host: localhost:49111
13 >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` to be an array with a single item in it, which is a string or comma separated headers.

You should set it to be an associative array where each key/value pair is a single header.

You also need to spell the header name correctly. Content-Type has a hyphen in the middle, not an underscore.

```
$headers = array(
    "X_RESTBUS_MESSAGE_ID" => $X_RESTBUS_MESSAGE_ID,
    "X_BU_ID"              => $X_BU_ID,
    "Content-Type"         => $Content_Type
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: Yes. I figured it out. Thanks